# MouseClick in shape Position Detection

Tags: java, java-2d

im learning Java2D, and one of my exercises is to create  a memory card game, but im strugling in the part to detect the shape of my rectangle when is clicked, im getting the position of the rectangle when is clicked, but when i use the method contain to check if the coordenates of the shape is inside of the area, my mouseclick can´t detect it. above i leave me code:

Screen.class:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
                Cartas c = cards.get(i); 
                System.out.println(c.getBoundingBox());
                if(c.getBoundingBox().contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                    System.out.println("Rectangle clicked");
                }               
            }
        }
```

Cards.class

```
public Rectangle getBoundingBox()
    {
        return new Rectangle(this.posX, this.posX, 38, 50); 
    }
```

Comment: `return new Rectangle(this.posX, this.posX, 38, 50); ` Shouldn't one of those be a Y instead of an X ?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @John3136 your right, my bad :S